# How do I get changed Value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobx-react

I have something like this

```
@action changeValue(event){
    console.log('value', event.target.value);
}

let dueDate = moment(task.dueDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
input type="date" className="task-due-date" value={dueDate} onChange={(event) => changeValue(event)}
```

Nothing is in event.target.value. I have some proxy event object but target has nothing. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use refs. Something like this:

```
class MapContainer extends Component {
  changeUser() {
    console.log(this.refs.user.value)
  } 
  render() {
    return (<input ref="user" type="text" onChange={this.changeUser.bind(this)} />)
  }
}
```

note the ref attribute in the input and the binding of this in the onChange attribute, that way you can access the refs object in the changeUser function to get your new value.